# Ruby regular expression method !~

Tags: ruby, regex, string, rdoc

I don't remember where I learned the `!~` method of the `String` class. However I know it compares a string to a regex and check whether the string not match the regex. See my below example.

```
C:\>irb
irb(main):001:0> "abba" =~ /(\w)(\w)\2\1/i
=> 0
irb(main):002:0> "xxxx" =~ /(\w)(\w)\2\1/i
=> 0
irb(main):003:0> "asdf" =~ /(\w)(\w)\2\1/i
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> "asdf" !~ /(\w)(\w)\2\1/i
=> true
irb(main):005:0> "asdf" !~ /asdf/i
=> false
irb(main):006:0>
```

I want to find more information of the method but I can't find it in the rdoc of both `String` and `Regexp`. Anyone can give some help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this is the method you can find it [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/) in the Methods filter.
I've found [this](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-21-7E) description.

> **obj !~ other → true or false**
>
> Returns true if two objects do not match (using the =~ method), otherwise false.

Comment: Thanks for the right direction. It's a method of the Kernel module, which was mixined by the Object class.