# Why does Ruby define Object#=~?

Tags: ruby

After reading a comment to an answer in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001250/ruby-regular-expression-method) and doing a little research, I see that `=~` is defined on `Object` and then overridden by `String` and `Regexp`. The implementations for `String` and `Regexp` appear to assume the other class:

```
"123" =~ "123" # => TypeError: type mismatch: String given
/123/ =~ /123/ # => TypeError: can't convert Regexp to String
```

Although `=~` is defined for `Object`, `+` is not:

```
Object.new =~ 1 # => nil
Object.new + 1 # => undefined method `+' for #<Object:0x556d38>
```

Why has `Object#=~` been defined, rather than restricting `=~` to to `String` and `Regexp`?

Comment: FWIW, it's defined in object.c as `static VALUE
rb_obj_match(VALUE obj1, VALUE obj2) { return Qnil; }`.

Comment: Did some googling, and there doesn't seem to be much of an answer anywhere.

Comment: @Dogbert I saw that.  Maybe looking through the Subversion history would shed light on this.

Comment: @EricWalker, [here's the commit](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/9d8075b99cf131e0b2522bcf82a5b47e82d3882e). Doesn't seem to help answer the question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it allows any object to be used in a match expression:

```
Object.new =~ /abc/
=> nil
```

I guess this makes sense in the way that `Object.new` does not match the regexp `/abc/` and the code would blow up if the left argument wasn't a `String` object. So it generally simplifies the code because you can have any object on the left side of the `=~` operator.

Comment: It seems like there's more than simple convenience going on here -- see my comment to @raina77ow's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I suppose that's actually nicely answered in String `=~` [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-3D-7E):

> **Match** — If obj is a `Regexp`, use it as a pattern to match against str,and
>   returns the position the match starts, or `nil` if there is no match.
>
> Otherwise, invokes `obj.=~`, passing `str` as an argument. The default `=~`
>   in Object returns `nil`.

The point is, you can write your own implementation of Object `=~` - and it will be used in `String =~ Not Regexp` statement.

Comment: This is not answering much. When would you want to use `String =~ Not Regexp`?

Comment: Also, why not do that with `+` as well (which is not defined for `Object`, unlike `=~`) -- that's what's not very clear to me.  It's almost like there was an additional thought going into it beyond convenience, e.g., a change in approach, a specific problem case, etc.

Answer (score 2):

From your comments, your actual question is why is `=~` defined on `Object` while `+` isn't.

The reason is that `Object#=~` can return `nil` for random objects (since they don't match), but `Object#+` can not return a meaningful result.

It is not necessarily super useful, but it can not be said to be false (you would have to show a match to prove that a `nil` result is a contradiction). See the mathematical concept of [vacuous truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth). On the other hand, any result for `Object.new + 1` could lead to contradictions.

This is similar to `<=>` that can return `nil` (and is thus also defined on `Object`) while `<`, `>`, ..., can not return `true` nor `false` while being completely consistent. Note that for `Class#>` it was decided to return `nil` in those cases.

Comment: I appreciate the point.  But I don't see how `Object.new =~ 1` is more meaningful than `Object.new + 1`.

Comment: Tried editing my answer. Can you provide a meaningful result for `Object.new + 1`? Do you agree that `Object.new <=> 1 #=> nil` is logical?

Comment: +1 for an interesting discussion. It seems to me like there could be the following cases here: (1a) there was a clear reason, and one or more responders here have gotten it; (1b) there is a clear reason, and it hasn't been mentioned yet; and (2) there was no compelling reason, it was just done this way without too much thought going into it.  I'm not convinced yet that we have (1a), yet. I didn't intend to ask a question I would have a hard time approving an answer to.

Comment: I do agree that `Object.new <=> 1 #=> nil` is logical.  I'm not convinced that `Object.new =~ 1 #=> nil` falls into the same category, though. It seems just as likely that it would have been a good idea to raise an exception in the latter instance, as is done with other operators.